# Auto post with facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sharer, rfid, user-presence

I'm using facebook login (with facebook api) for one of my web application .

After user logged with their FB account I'm assigning secret unique code for the user in my application side .

So now I need to login to the particular user FB account automatically and post pre-defined message on that user wall when user enter that unique code (Actually users are using RFID tags sometimes they will enter that code manually)

So Is it possible to do that automatic login to the FB ?

Comment: did you manage it? i am looking for something similar. In my case i am trying to start with a simple "like" action

Answer (score 0):

Sounds a bit fishy ....

still:

https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

you can extend a users token for 60 days ...

cheers